# Overview of features in Clojure coming from other languages than CL

Tags: clojure, language-features, common-lisp

I am searching for an overview of the features of Clojure that are coming from other languages than Common Lisp.

For example:

- STM: language X, Y and Z

Your input is welcome!

Comment: ref types: ML family; MVCC STM: databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some features loosely based on other languages that I am aware of:

- Lazy evaluation / lazy lists : Haskell
- Persistent [data structures](http://clojure.org/data_structures) : Haskell and other pure functional languages
- [Dynamic typing](http://clojure.org/dynamic): any dynamic language e.g. Groovy, Javascript
- Type hinting (for performance): various languages
- Code-is-data and [macro based](http://clojure.org/macros) meta-programming: LISP
- JVM execution and [interoperability](http://clojure.org/java_interop): Groovy, Scala

Ideas in Clojure that I believe are pretty original:

- Clojure-style [concurrent programming with STM](http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming)
- Clojure [protocols](http://clojure.org/protocols) (somewhat like interfaces but more powerful)

Comment: Protocols I think come from Objective-C.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to have a look at this [list of books, that influenced Clojure's design](http://www.amazon.com/gp/richpub/listmania/fullview/R3LG3ZBZS4GCTH), compiled by Rich Hickey himself. Looking at the titles you'll probably figure out where more of the ideas originated.

Answer (score 0):

**STM in clojure is coming from hard  research in concurrency and transaction field  and have implementations in Haskell(Glasgow Compiler) and more recently Fortress( High Performance Numeric Computation Language by Sun)**